# corona sdk. can I get the parent class of a object?

Tags: oop, lua, addeventlistener, coronasdk

I have a 2d array of objects, the objects contain a text object and a boolean parameter called "hold". I'd like to be able to change the text colour and change the hold paramater when you click on the text. At the moment I have a tap eventlistener on all the text objects and I can change the colour no problem using the event.target, but how would I be able to change the "hold" parameter which is a sibling of the text object? is there anything like event.target.parent???

heres the pertinent code...

```
    --CONSTRUCTOR in dice.lua

    function dice.new(x, y) 

    local newdice = {hold = false, dicetext = display.newText(math.random(1,6), 50*x , 50*y , nil, 50)} 

    return setmetatable(newdice, dice_mt) 
    end


            --2d array (this and the rest of the code is from main.lua)


    mainarray = {}

    for x = 1, 5, 1 do
    mainarray[x] = {}

    for y = 1, 5, 1 do
    mainarray[x][y] = diceclass.new(x,y)

    end
    end


            --add event listeners to text

    for x = 1, 5, 1 do
    for y = 1, 5, 1 do
    mainarray[x][y].dicetext:addEventListener("tap", bloop)
    end
    end


            --function that is called

    function bloop(event)
    print("bloop")
    print(event.target)
    event.target:setTextColor(255,0,0)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I just added a hold parameter to the text object itself! That did the trick!